# Diferencia entre estos dos comandos de la terminal Linux?

Tags: shell, terminal

Hola amigos soy un poco nuevo en la terminal de Linux, estoy usando Ubuntu y viendo uno de los comandos en especifico este

```
cd
```

.

estoy viendo que tiene dos forma de entrar a un directorio

asi:

```
 cd /usr/bin
```

y asi :

```
cd ./bin
```

Cual seria el beneficio  **En un ambito ya de administracion**

Lo lamento si la pregunta es muy basica pero realmente no entiendo cual es la diferencia entre estos dos comandos cual es el PRO y CONTRA de cada uno.

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucd.htm Te ayudara bastante alli muestra la diferencia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> no entiendo cual es la diferencia entre estos dos comandos

Lógico que no veas la diferencia: **no la hay**.

El comando `cd` (**c**hange **d**irectory) se limita a cambiar nuestro directorio de trabajo actual. No hay mas.

Simplemente, si haces `cd /root`, estas indicando que quieres acceder a un directorio que se llama `root`, y que está situado (su padre es) **el directorio raiz** del sistema.

Si haces `cd ./bin`, estas indicando que quieres acceder a un directorio de nombre `bin`, y que está situado (su padre es) **el directorio de trabajo actual**.

Esta última forma es equivalente a `cd bin`. En ausencia de un *padre* **explícito**, se asume que el padre es el directorio de trabajo actual.

Hay 3 *padres* especiales:

> /

El directorio raiz del sistema; es el origen de la jerarquía de directorios.

> .

El directorio de trabajo **actual**. Es aquél en el que nos encontramos ahora mismo.

> ..

El directorio **padre** del actual.

¿ Como cambio de directorio ? Pues según te convenga. Si vas a entrar en el directorio `Descargas`, situado en tu `$HOME`, y ya estás en `/home/MIUSUARIO`, es mas rápido (de escribir y de ejecutar) hacer

```
cd Descargas
```

que indicar la ruta completa:

```
cd /home/MIUSUARIO/Descargas
```

Sin embargo, si ya estás en `Descargas` y quieres ir al directorio raiz, es mucho más rápido

```
cd /
```

que poner, uno a uno, todos los pasos intermedios:

```
cd ../../..
```

#### Nota técnica

En realidad, el directorio `/` **si** es especial. Los otros 2; `.` y `..` **no**. Son entradas de directorio *reales*, que se encuentran en todos los directorios del sistema, y que *apuntan* respectivamente a si mismos y al directorio padre.

Así, cada vez que el sistema intenta *interpretar* un nombre de directorio, la comparación es simple:

- ¿ Empieza por `/` ? -> Salto al directorio raiz y comienzo a buscar por ahí.
- ¿ No empieza por `/` ? -> Comienzo a buscar en el directorio actual.

Ese es el motivo de que `cd ./hola` y `cd hola` sean *equivalentes*:

- cd `./hola`

Comienzo en el directorio actual -> busco un directorio llamado `.` -> entro en él (como apunta a si mismo, nos quedamos donde estamos) -> busco `hola` -> entro en él.

- cd `hola`

Comienzo en el directorio actual -> busco `hola` -> entro en él.